# database folder is missing in device file explorer in android studio

Tags: android

I have created a sqlite database and table in android studio, but the sqlite database folder is missing in the device's file explorer.
I have written the following code in the `databasehelper.java` class

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   db.execSQL("create table "+TABLE_NAME+"(sr INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, datetime TEXT, location TEXT, odometer INTEGER, speed INTEGER, GPS TEXT, int.volt INTEGER, ext.volt INTEGER )");
}
```

Comment: Adding complete database helper class can help to get answer so please add.

Comment: yes..  i have already added.

Comment: is there any error you are seeing on creating table or db in logcat??

Comment: com.google.android.play.b.g.a(421): Failed to connect to server: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
09-21 11:24:18.337 1599-1612/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module

Comment: @kj007 here is logcat-E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
09-25 15:55:06.368 10217-10248/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
09-25 15:55:06.384 10217-10248/? E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mE

Comment: Supriya if you can push your demo code to GitHub and share url will help to look at

Answer (score 2):

There might be a possibility that you have not connected the android device in USB file transfer mode. I had this issue in Android 9 and fixed it by connecting the device in USB file transfer mode.

Answer (score 0):

The default location of database is

```
/data/data/<your_app_packagename>/databases/db_name.
```

It is not accessible in non-rooted devices. You can create your database in different location for debugging.

Comment: but database folder is not there in my package. i am not able to solve this issue

Comment: You do not have permissions to view this path. Can you tell the path in which you are looking?

Answer (score 0):

solved this issue.
now my database folder is visible in device file explorer.
i delete my old database. also remove databaseHelper class. and create a fresh database and table.
may be i missed some steps while creating database thats why database folder is missing.
now its working..
thank you for ur help

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to check that your database is successfully created or not, if your database is created then you can follow these steps:

- Step1 : Debug you device with the breakpoint on the createdatabase().
- Step2 : After the successfully database create, Open the Device File Explorer, Go to the your Package and right click onto the package name.
- Step3: Synchronize you package, now you will get your Database

Answer (score 0):

1 create table
2 upgrade table
3 insert value in table
4 (make sure that) add table field in List
and call the method in MainActivity
eg. - db.gelAlldata();
5 then run and synchronize ur project package